# Extract option not working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I tried to extract .zip files by simply "Right-click-> Extract Here" but it is generating an empty folder. Earlier, it used to work fine but now it is not. Using terminal to unzip is working properly. But I want to fix this manual way of extracting. Someone, please help. Thank You